# How to join all different rows with the same ID but a different date and return it as a unique row with new columns like DATE_0, DATE_1, DATE_2, ...?

Tags: sql, firebird

Consider this table:

```
+----+------------+
| ID | DATE       |
+----+------------+
| 0  | 01/12/2007 |
| 0  | 15/02/2018 |
| 1  | 21/05/2006 |
| 1  | 03/12/2017 |
| 1  | 01/03/2007 |
| 1  | 23/11/2018 |
| 2  | 15/10/2019 |
| 3  | 11/10/2019 |
| 3  | 22/07/2000 |
| 4  | 08/05/2001 |
| 4  | 07/03/1998 |
+----+------------+
```

I need a SQL query so this table will become like this:

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ID | DATE_0     | DATE_1     | DATE_2     | DATE_3     |
+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 0  | 01/12/2007 | 15/02/2018 | NULL       | NULL       |
| 1  | 21/05/2006 | 03/12/2017 | 01/03/2007 | 23/11/2018 |
| 2  | 15/10/2019 | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       |
| 3  | 11/10/2019 | 22/07/2000 | NULL       | NULL       |
| 4  | 08/05/2001 | 07/03/1998 | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I already know that the maximum number same ID rows won't exceed 4.

Comment: I removed the interbase tags: Firebird and InterBase may share a common starting point 20 years ago, they are not the same database system.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select
    id,
    max(case when rn = 1 then date end) date_0,
    max(case when rn = 2 then date end) date_1,
    max(case when rn = 3 then date end) date_2,
    max(case when rn = 4 then date end) date_3
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by id order by date) rn
    from mytable
) t
group by id
```

Please note that this does not exactly produce the result that you expect, in the sense that dates are distributed in the columns by ascending value. If you want to use a different ordering criteria, you can change the `order by` part of `row_number()`.